# Python SMTPD library override version

Tags: python, smtpd

I'd like to emit my own message when someone connects to this smtp server.

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class FakeSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    __version__ = 'TEST EMAIL SERVER'

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smtp_server = FakeSMTPServer(('localhost', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        smtp_server.close()
```

However, I am still getting the response:

```
220 Win7-PC Python SMTP proxy version 0.2
```

How do I override the welcome message in python to see "TEST EMAIL SERVER"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
smtpd.__version__ = "TEST EMAIL SERVER"
```

somewhere (may be after import statements).